# How to limit a collection of objects related on a foreign key in Django Templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

Given is a model called "comment" with a foreign key relationship to a model called "task".

```
{% for task in tasks %}
  {% for comment in task.comment_set.all %}
    {{ comment }}
  {% endfor %}
...
```

What is the best way to limit this to 5 comments like:

```
Entry.objects.all()[:5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% for task in tasks %}
  {% for comment in task.comment_set.all|slice:"5" %}
    {{ comment }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks, that one works as well.
Which one is the better approach?

Comment: Well there are many django template tags/filters that allow such a slight manipulation of data, so i wouldn't see such a big violation of the mvc concept there, also django has a slightly different approach towards that concept: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/general/#django-appears-to-be-a-mvc-framework-but-you-call-the-controller-the-view-and-the-view-the-template-how-come-you-don-t-use-the-standard-names

Answer (score 1):

You don't. You should not do "real work" in a template, this breaks the [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller).

Do the real work in the view, and pass the data to the template (using the context dictionary).

```
def handle_comments(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.all()
    comments = {}
    for task in tasks:
      comments[task] = task.comment_set.all()[:5]
    return render_to_response('commenting.html', {'comments': comments})
```

You can then iterate over the comments in your template:

```
{% for task, task_comments in comments.items %}{{ task }}{% endfor %}
```